# Create new column of closest values according to another column by groups

Tags: r, performance, loops, data.table

I have the following data frame (called `mydata_tsample`):

```
cusip_id     trd_exctn_dt   trd_exctn_tm    price   contra_party_type **refPrice**
BUHADU       01.04.2016     01:10:50        101.00  C                 102.10
BUHADU       01.04.2016     02:10:50        101.50  C                 102.10    
BUHADU       01.04.2016     08:10:50        102.10  D                 102.10
BUHADU       01.04.2016     09:10:50        102.10  C                 102.10
BUHADU       02.04.2016     07:12:50        90.50   C                 90.85
BUHADU       02.04.2016     09:10:55        90.85   D                 90.85
BUHADU       02.04.2016     12:11:40        90.90   C                 91.00
BUHADU       02.04.2016     12:12:02        91.00   D                 91.00
XDSEOI       03.04.2016     06:52:51        50.00   D                 50.00 
XDSEOI       03.04.2016     08:40:58        50.20   C                 50.00  
XDSEOI       03.04.2016     15:10:51        51.00   C                 52.00
XDSEOI       03.04.2016     15:14:51        52.00   D                 52.00
```

I'd like to generate/add a new column (called `refPrice`) that is calculated using a for loop.
For each row in column `RefPrice`, I'd like to extract the price with following conditions:

1. same `cusip_ID`
2. same `trd_exctn_dt`
3. `contra_party_type` = D
4. then take the closest price to `trd_exctn_tm`

I did a code that does exactly this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata_tsample)){
      Mtx_aftr_CUSIP=mydata_tsample[mydata_tsample$cusip_id %in% mydata_tsample[i,1],]
      Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP[Mtx_aftr_CUSIP$trd_exctn_dt %in% mydata_tsample[i,2],]
      Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt[Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt$contra_party_type %in% "D",]
      if(nrow(Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer)==0) {next} else 
      {
        closesttime=which.min(abs(Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer$trd_exctn_tm - mydata_tsample[i,3]))
        mydata_tsample$RefPrice[i]=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer[closesttime,4]  }
}
```

The problem I have is speed. I takes me a couple of hours to process 0.5Mio. lines. In total I have 5Mio. lines...

I tried with `doParallel`, but I did not work out.

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
library(foreach)
foreach(i=1:nrow(mydata_tsample)) %dopar% {
  Mtx_aftr_CUSIP=mydata_tsample[mydata_tsample$cusip_id %in% mydata_tsample[i,1],]
  Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP[Mtx_aftr_CUSIP$trd_exctn_dt %in% mydata_tsample[i,2],]
  Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt[Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt$contra_party_type %in% "D",]
  if(nrow(Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer)==0) {next} else 
  {
    closesttime=which.min(abs(Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer$trd_exctn_tm - mydata_tsample[i,3]))
    mydata_tsample$RefPrice[i]=Mtx_aftr_CUSIP_dt_dealer[closesttime,4]
  }
}

}
```

Comment: I think you need group by operation

Comment: thank you akrun. Would that speed up the performance?

Comment: The way you describe your algorithm, `refprice` would always be the same as `price`, because the closest time to a row's `trd_extn_time` would be the row itself. Do you mean the closest neighbour that is different?

Comment: Closest  `D` type ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple partial solution that runs in seconds, and gets the nearest *previous* price where `contra_party_type=="D"`.

```
# generate toy data:
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
n <- 500000
dfr <- dplyr::tibble(
  cusip_id = sample(LETTERS, n, replace = TRUE),
  trd_exctn_dt = as.Date(sample(365, n, replace = TRUE), 
    origin = "2016-01-01"),
  trd_exctn_tm = strftime(as.POSIXlt(sample(60*60*24, n, replace = TRUE),
    origin = "1970-01-01"), "%H:%M:%S"),
  price = round(rnorm(n, 100, 5), 2),
  contra_party_type = sample(LETTERS[1:4], n, replace = TRUE)
)


dfr <- dfr %>% 
      group_by(cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt) %>% 
      arrange(trd_exctn_tm, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
      mutate(
        refprice = ifelse(contra_party_type == "D", price, NA),
        refprice = zoo::na.locf(refprice, na.rm = FALSE)
      )
dfr

# A tibble: 500,000 x 6
# Groups:   cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt [9,490]
   cusip_id trd_exctn_dt trd_exctn_tm price contra_party_type refprice
   <chr>    <date>       <chr>        <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
 1 A        2016-01-02   00:25:47      89.6 D                     89.6
 2 A        2016-01-02   01:19:37     101.  B                     89.6
 3 A        2016-01-02   01:22:34     108.  B                     89.6
 4 A        2016-01-02   01:28:14     102.  D                    102. 
 5 A        2016-01-02   01:35:36      95.9 A                    102. 
 6 A        2016-01-02   01:45:01     102.  C                    102.
```

To do exactly what you want, I would

- calculate the time difference to the last previous instance where cpt is D
- calculate the time difference to the next future instance where cpt is D
- calculate the prices for each of those instances
- choose the price based on the closest time difference, using `ifelse`

Comment: What a smart solution which runs in a couple of secs - thank you. I will try to solve the problem of the "nearest" value in the next couple of days. many thanks dash2!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **really fast** solution using a rolling join with `data.table` which takes only a couple of ms on 500000 rows:

**Data:**

```
dt <- fread("cusip_id  trd_exctn_dt   trd_exctn_tm    price   contra_party_type
                 BUHADU   01.04.2016     01:10:50        101.00  C
                 BUHADU   01.04.2016     02:10:50        101.50  C    
                 BUHADU   01.04.2016     08:10:50        102.10  D
                 BUHADU   01.04.2016     09:10:50        102.10  C
                 BUHADU   02.04.2016     07:12:50        90.50   C
                 BUHADU   02.04.2016     09:10:55        90.85   D
                 BUHADU   02.04.2016     12:11:40        90.90   C
                 BUHADU   02.04.2016     12:12:02        91.00   D
                 XDSEOI   03.04.2016     06:52:51        50.00   D 
                 XDSEOI   03.04.2016     08:40:58        50.20   C  
                 XDSEOI   03.04.2016     15:10:51        51.00   C
                 XDSEOI   03.04.2016     15:14:51        52.00   D
                 XDSEOI   03.04.2016     23:59:00        58.00   D
                 XDSEOI   04.04.2016     01:00:00        52.00   C
                 XDSEOI   04.04.2016     15:14:51        55.00   D")
```

**Code:**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Convert trd_exctn_tm to number of seconds (or create a new column)
dt[, trd_exctn_tm := as.numeric(hms(x = trd_exctn_tm)),]

# set keys
setkey(dt, cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt, trd_exctn_tm)

# keep rollin rollin rollin...
dt[contra_party_type == "D", .(cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt, trd_exctn_tm, RefPrice=price),][dt,, roll = "nearest"]
```

**Output:**

```
    cusip_id trd_exctn_dt trd_exctn_tm RefPrice  price contra_party_type
 1:   BUHADU   01.04.2016         4250   102.10 101.00                 C
 2:   BUHADU   01.04.2016         7850   102.10 101.50                 C
 3:   BUHADU   01.04.2016        29450   102.10 102.10                 D
 4:   BUHADU   01.04.2016        33050   102.10 102.10                 C
 5:   BUHADU   02.04.2016        25970    90.85  90.50                 C
 6:   BUHADU   02.04.2016        33055    90.85  90.85                 D
 7:   BUHADU   02.04.2016        43900    91.00  90.90                 C
 8:   BUHADU   02.04.2016        43922    91.00  91.00                 D
 9:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016        24771    50.00  50.00                 D
10:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016        31258    50.00  50.20                 C
11:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016        54651    52.00  51.00                 C
12:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016        54891    52.00  52.00                 D
13:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016        86340    58.00  58.00                 D
14:   XDSEOI   04.04.2016         3600    55.00  52.00                 C
15:   XDSEOI   04.04.2016        54891    55.00  55.00                 D
```

---

**Explanations:**

The first part of our data.table operation

```
dt[contra_party_type == "D", .(cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt, trd_exctn_tm, RefPrice=price),]
```

can be translated to

*Take `dt`, subset rows where `contra... == "D"`, select columns `cusip_id`, ..., and `RefPrice` which equals `price`.*

So this `data.table` looks like

```
   cusip_id trd_exctn_dt trd_exctn_tm RefPrice
1:   BUHADU   01.04.2016     08:10:50   102.10
2:   BUHADU   02.04.2016     09:10:55    90.85
3:   BUHADU   02.04.2016     12:12:02    91.00
4:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016     06:52:51    50.00
5:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016     15:14:51    52.00
6:   XDSEOI   03.04.2016     23:59:00    58.00
7:   XDSEOI   04.04.2016     15:14:51    55.00
```

Saving it as `dt2` and setting the same keys with `setkey(dt, cusip_id, trd_exctn_dt, trd_exctn_tm)`, we can go over to the second part of our command:

```
dt2[dt,, roll = "nearest"]
```

For the purpose of understanding change it to

```
dt2[dt,,]
```

and look at the result. You can see that we joined both tables by our `key` columns. `RefPrice` was added to `dt`. But there are `NA`s in `RefPrice`, because these rows were not found in `dt2`. To get rid of these `NA`s we use `roll = "nearest"`, meaning *take the closest value of `RefPrice` in `dt2` according to `trd_exctn_tm` and fill these rows*.